# How to call web api in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am developing an extension using typescript,and I don't know how to use typescript to call web API, anyone know or can provide an sample to me?

Comment: Typescript gets compiled to Javascript (I'm sure you know that). So figure out how you want to do this in Javascript: a) find an existing library written by someone else, b) write your own, c) ???.  If you find an existing solution you like, see if there is a Typescript definition (on DefinitelyTyped) for this library. Then you can simply reference that file. To write your own, you need to use XMLHTTPRequest (google it).

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is compiled into javascript, in Javascript specifically node environemnt, there are many ways to make an HTTP call to the web API.
You can use these libraries:

1. axios
2. got
3. node-fetch

These libraries have type definitions.

Answer (score -3):

> I am developing an extension using typescript,and I don't know how to use typescript to call web API, anyone know or can provide an sample to me

You need to write code generation code *specific* to your APP + front end framework.

For starters checkout http://type.litesolutions.net/

---

Just another reason to consider [NodeJS](https://medium.com/@basarat/issues-with-polyglot-programming-8f9ba0bfcb47).

Comment: this doesn't answer the question or provide a good reason as to why the solution being sought isn't a beneficial one.